# Create Craft 3 Plugin - Call to a member function getVersion() on null

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, twigextension

I'm trying to write my own Craft 3 TWIG filter / functions.

For this purpose I created a scaffolding using pluginfactory.io. I did a `composer require` and composer correctly symlinks the plugin to the Craft project's vendor directory. When I click "Plugins" in the CP it shows my plugin, but when I click "Install" I get the error:

**Call to a member function getVersion() on null**

caused in /var/www/html/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/Plugins.php on line 328 which is

```
$info = [
  'handle' => $handle,
  'version' => $plugin->getVersion(), // <== Line 328
  'schemaVersion' => $plugin->schemaVersion,
  'installDate' => Db::prepareDateForDb(new \DateTime()),
];
```

Why? I compared my composer.json with e.g. nystudio107/craft3-pathtools and it's almost identical and I definitely have a version defined in my composer.json.

Why is $plugin null?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you edit the question and share you main plugin class file (if it has one) as well as your plugin's `composer.json`?

Comment: hey brad: see answer below, only idea: maybe craft should check if the file exists before not being able to initiate the plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shame on me, but maybe still interesting to others who have this problem: I'm using vagrant and the path of my extension was NOT mounted to the vagrant box. That's all. So it simply could not find the files. Maybe a warning by craft would be nice, that it can not load the plugin files

Though I do not understand, why it found the composer.json to read the basic information, which showed up in the Plugins section of Craft...